# C++ Exception Handling on Tizen

Tags: c++, exception, tizen, tizen-native-app

Can anyone explain the exception handling in Tizen?

In FAQ i found:

> Q: Can I use C++ try-catch exception handling?
>
> A: No, C++ try-catch exception handling is not supported in Tizen.

But in my experiments c++ try catch is working fine when testing on a Tizen Device.

Here is what I did:

1. Open Tizen SDK
2. Create an Empty Tizen Native C++ project
3. In main Put a try catch statement. Put logs in catch and try.

Does this mean that i can use try catch for my methods but not for Tizen APIs and Classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this mean that i can use try catch for my methods but not for Tizen APIs and Classes?

Yes. From [the online documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.tizen.native.appprogramming%2Fhtml%2Fapp_dev_process%2Foverview_of_app_dev.htm):

> Error handling in Tizen works differently compared to standard C++. Tizen uses error results instead of C++ exceptions, due to historical reasons.
>   ...
>   **The above exception handling model only affects the Tizen platform**. When developing your own application, **you can use the C++ exception handling mechanism as well. Handle exceptions for your own code with either Tizen exceptions or C++ exceptions**.

Comment: Thankx I was confused by the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

this remind me bada design :

> error results instead of C++ exceptions, since C++ exceptions require
>   too large of a runtime for resource-constrained devices, and thus
>   incur too much overhead.

[source](http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppappprogramming.help/html/basics_bada_programming/exception_handling.htm)